# Sentry token in repository via sentry.properties

Tags: git, react-native, sentry

While my DSN is in a .env file and hidden from the repo browsers, I find it disturbing that my auth token is in the sentry.properties file for all to see.
I'm having trouble understanding what this means and how much of a security risk is it to let people outside my organization read this file?
(I have outsourced developers doing odd jobs for me on the repo)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We recommend treating a `sentry.properties` like an `.env` file.

It is basically the same, so you should add it to your e.g. `.gitignore`.

The reason why it's called `sentry.properties` is because of android gradle, we needed it to be read natively.

Comment: if we gitignore this file, how do we provide this information to the ci server for automatic deployments? currently the ci server picks it up from within the git repo

Comment: @gaurav5430 In Sentry official cli docs it says that these values can be configured using environment variables https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/#configure-sentry-cli

Comment: @kachar Does this also applies for React Native projects? Cause for RN projects the `sentry.properties` file is inside `ios/` and `android/`

Comment: Yeah I can add it to .gitignore file but I'm uncomfortable with leaving it in my app, cause when I bundle the app, it's possible for the app to be reversed-engineered and the token will be visible.

Right now, I use the --dart-define-from-file to handle all my secret keys in the app but I'm not sure how to use this with sentry.properties file.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively to the `sentry.properties` file, the cli can be configured using environment variables as the docs says:

- https://docs.sentry.io/product/cli/configuration/#configuration-values
- https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/#configure-sentry-cli

| Property name | Environment variable |
| --- | --- |
| `defaults.url` | `SENTRY_URL` |
| `defaults.org` | `SENTRY_ORG` |
| `defaults.project` | `SENTRY_PROJECT` |
| `auth.token` | `SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN` |

The environment variables will take precedence over values set in the properties file

In this way you can set the static fields in `sentry.properties` like url, org, project and pass as Env only the `SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN` in CI mode

Comment: Does this also applies for React Native projects? Cause for RN projects the `sentry.properties` file is inside `ios/` and `android/`

Comment: @ChanJingHong for React Native you might wanna check the docs  at https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/configuration/environments/. Anyway Sentry CLI is not running in React Native environment, so it should be a concern of the deployment procedure (CI).